# Latex compatible code for both siunitx version 1 and 2

Tags: siunitx

On one system, I have siunitx version 1 and on another, I have version 2 (I think).

I already converted my code to be compatible with version 1, so that my table looks like:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} |c|S[tabformat=3.2]|c| @{}}
...
```

And my import looks like:

```
\usepackage[load-configurations = version-1]{siunitx}
```

However, that doesn't work with siunitx 1. It throws an error that the load configuration is unknown. The error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `load-configurations' for package `siunitx'.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.3894 \ifx
\@empty\si@emulate\@empty\else
The option `load-configurations' was not declared in package `siunitx', perhaps
you
misspelled its name. Try typing <return> to proceed.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/siunitx/config/si-prefix.cfg
File: si-prefix.cfg 2009/09/21 v1.3a siunitx: SI Multiple prefixes
```

How can I fix this so that it works with both versions?

Comment: This should work but we'll need a fully example to help.

Comment: Could you give us an MWE please? Why can't you upgrade your `siunitx` on the other system? Please first check your current versions by adding `\listfiles` into your preamble. Read out the version of `siunitx` from the `.log` file.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'd assume we are looking at TL'07 or TL'09 in a 'long term support' Linux distro here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I can't upgrade because our administrators like to keep the Ubuntu LTS version.

Comment: You could try to add the option through the documentclass: `\documentclass[load-configurations=version-1]{article}`. Then the older siunitx (which doesn't know it) will ignore it, but the newer one will see it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *force* version 2 to load the version 1 options without using `load-configurations` then you can put a v1 option into the load line, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tabformat=2.2]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{10}{\m}

\begin{tabular}{S[tabformat=3.2]}
  123.45 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the idea of having an explicit option to load the older options is that you really should have the *same* version of packages across systems.

Comment: You can happily use a newer version of `siunitx` with an older TeX system by having a copy inside your personal tree (`~/texmf`  on Linux). You'd also need a couple of support items here but it is quite doable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see the `v1` option. Did you forget it? About local installation: I could do that but then it would still not work for all other people here at our institute. I don't like to have special installation instructions for people to work with the Latex code.

Comment: Ah, I guess you mean that `tabformat=2.2` is a v1 option. I tried that, however, in the table itself, I get errors like `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.`.

Comment: Maybe I can check somehow for texlive 2009 version or so? Or is there some `try`/`except` in Tex, so I can first try with `load-configurations = version-1` and then without?

Comment: @Albert The trick I've used is that loading `siunitx` v2 with a v1 option forces back-compatibly mode. You have to load with some 'older' option to get this to work, even if it's a no-op (so one of the defaults).